# how to debug the kernelcrash on pi at bootup process

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I have build a kernel image using toolchain and flashed on Pi2 board and it's working fine.when i tried with my own module with kernel crash(null pointer derefference)statically and build the image and flashed on pi2 board.At the bootup time I'm getting kernel panic.I want to know how to find the the location of my crash using those kerenl panic message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuOse.jpg)

Comment: One way to do it would be to debug via serial console or JTAG, or the other hand is there a function name you recognize on the stack trace ?

Comment: from stack trace i'm getting only stack and call trace addresses.how to identify the crash using those address.@dvhh

Comment: Using [addr2line](https://linux.die.net/man/1/addr2line) could help, see this [explanation](https://elinux.org/Addr2line_for_kernel_debugging)